# Performing GLM within python script on windows 7 64

Tags: python, windows, r, scipy, glm

I'm trying to perform GLM (Generalized linear model) repeatedly within a python script (within a loop).

1- I tried to use Stats within Scipy glm function but description is quite inexistant and I think I did not use it well --> error message

```
"ValueError: only ttest_ind implemented".
```

I searched within stats.py file and in _support.py to find my way without results.

2- I have tried to install RPY2 (hope that lgautier or other will read me) ot use R powered functions. But I'm on windows 7 64, and it seems that I did not succeed to install it well. I have error message:

```
    import rpy2.tests
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\tests.py", line 3, in 
    import rpy2.robjects.tests
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 12, in 
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 22, in 
    "This might be because R.exe is nowhere in your Path.")
RuntimeError: Unable to determine R version from the registery.Calling the command 'R RHOME' does not return anything.
This might be because R.exe is nowhere in your Path.
```

How to perform robust GLM in python (other ways?, I tried good ones but I missed ...?)?
How to install RPY (noob/basic student learner) on windows 7 64 and interface it with python?

Comment: There is no question here. Looks like you failed to install rpy2 properly, so I would subscribe to the rpy list and describe what you did there.  Someone may be able to help you.

Comment: You probably don't want the 64-bit version of Python; it's not very well supported as far as extensions and third-party libraries go. If you use an x86 version of Python you should have problems installing it from a binary.

Comment: @ Dirk:  my question is how to perform a basal statistic test in a powered programming language as python. I have perform some searches before asking and I did not succeed. So I humbly looking for help.

Comment: ...(sorry, continuation) How to perform a GLM in python ("natively": using scipy?) or using alien libraries?

Comment: I've had a quick search for this but not come up with much. The scipy.stats.glm function doesn't seem to do it, and in any case is poorly documented. You might have to resort to reading McCullagh and Nelder's GLM book and implementing it yourself. It's not *that* difficult, and you can use the stats functions in scipy for distribution values. What family of model are you doing? Poisson, Binomial etc? Also you can cross-check your program with R's glm fit.

Comment: @Solenn: I do read this, and I note that 1/ there no MS Windows 64bit build for rpy2 available (no one contributed any), 2/ rpy2 for MS Windows is currently left behind (apparently no community-oriented interest in it from anyone). Sharing your build would give a chance to others to try reproduce your problem and may be find a solution to it.

Comment: What does your `path` (type that into your command line) say? Does it include R? Can you run R from the command line from anywhere (which indicates you have it in your path)? Is this still relevant? :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why the answers here seem to indicate that statsmodels test coverage for GLM is not that good. I wrote the tests. The models are verified against Stata, R, and SAS. They're pretty comprehensive. If you find something unexpected or this not to be the case then please report it to developers.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/scikits/statsmodels/genmod/tests/test_glm.py

Answer (score 1):

And shortly after my last comment, I find this:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/

with its GLM documentation here:

http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/glm.html

I'd strongly suggest cross-checking with R's fit as well to make sure it's doing what you think.

Answer (score -2):

I answer at me:

statsmodels are not developed and tested enough to be employed, so **DO NOT USE STATSMODELS** in its current version **to perform GLM** --> rpy2 is appropriate but need some complicated install (copy into /Pythonxx/Lib/site-packages/ folders extracted from rpy2 tar and get 'nose' and copy it at the same place)

Comment: What gives you this idea? The GLM code in scikits.statsmodels is tested and verified against Stata or R. If you want, you can check the test suite. If you actually find an edge case where it doesn't work, then report it to the developers.